How would you say a couple of letters (as in mail) if they're not necessarily letters?
I'm used to saying "a couple of pieces of mail".
But thinking of it, "pieces" seems a bit strange. But "mails" sounds even stranger. And "packages" would be incorrect, as would "letters" since I'm aiming for a general term that includes both.
So, is there a better term than "pieces" or should I continue using that?

Pieces is fine. The Wikipedia page uses it several times (as well as "mailpieces" which is a word I've never seen before).

I got stuff in the mail.

"But thinking of it, "pieces" seems a bit strange"  Piece of mail is 100.0% idiomatic and colloquial.

@StuartF The USPS Informed Delivery service uses "mailpieces" to describe things that aren't packages. I had never seen this usage either until just the other day.

"Articles of mail" might be a good one.  I could swear I've heard that a few times before.

"a couple of pieces of mail" seems fine but if it doesn't sit well with you for whatever reason then try "some mail"

"You've got mail!"

Can you explain how letters can be 'possibly not letters'? Are you talking about electronic mail here? Thus voicemail / email?

@EdwinAshworth I didn't mean that those letters might be emails. I meant that they might be packages for example. The admittedly awkward wording in the title is because I wasn't sure if pieces of mail would be correct, which is the reason for the question.

Note that "mails" is correct in some dialects and languages, but refers specifically to multiple individual emails, not physical articles of mail.


"But thinking of it, "pieces" seems a bit strange"

Piece of mail is 100.000% idiomatic and colloquial.
It's that simple.

"Idiomatic and colloquial" and "a bit strange" are not mutually exclusive.

Mr Lars!  Please don't confuse the matter.  (In general or for the OP if OO is still reading.) By "strange" the OP meant "not colloquial".  It is colloquial. The whole QA is that simple.  PS surely this should have been migrated to Learners'.  Signed, committee to FINALLY provide simple answers on this site to those questions which are simple

While it seems you're correct that it's fine to say pieces, at least in AmE. your assertion that The whole QA is that simple. is, I think, too extreme in light of the other answers and comments here. It might even not be the best word to use in BrE.

This is the answer I would have written, but I'm reluctant to up-vote it because it's too simple. Here, have my +1, but don't let it happen again :)

I downvoted it because it makes emphatic, oversimplified assertions well beyond the (lack of) presented evidence.

@Conrado the question is utterly trivial.  Let's examine ALL TWO sentences of the question. Stand back! we will now fully analyze BOTH. :)   (1) "I'm used to saying "a couple of pieces of mail". But thinking of it, "pieces" seems a bit strange."  Reply: you're wrong.  (2) "So, is there a better term than "pieces" or should I continue using that?"  No.

Some evidence to back up this answer: a Google ngrams graph shows “pieces of mail” outnumbers “items of mail” and “mail items”.  Closer inspection confirms this is mostly geunuine instances the usage we’re after, not e.g. references to armour.  Switching between corpuses, “pieces of mail” is very dominant in American English, more first-among-equals in British English; “mail items” is comparably frequent in BrE, but mostly in more technical contexts.

(cont’d) My personal intuition also strongly agrees with Fattie’s here, but when it comes down to conflicting claims of intuition, I think we do need to give evidence not just say “you’re wrong, I’m right”, however right we may believe ourselves to be…

"My personal intuition also strongly agrees with Fattie’s here" the logical conclusion is that you're right

Regarding the confusing "items of mail" issue, the instant someone mentioned it I instantly pointed it it was formal or technical, and of course that was correct. And the PLL Corpus Report™ (of course) confirms that I am correct - which is a given anyway.

LexisNexis has a glossary for the post and it seems postal item is the term you might be looking for. It is defined as:

(a) any letter, postcard or other such thing in writing as may be used by the sender for imparting information to the recipient, or (b) any packet or parcel.

LawInsider confirms and provides many similar definitions. For example:

Postal items means letter-post and parcels, as described in the Acts of the Universal Postal Union currently in force, when carried by or for the postal services.


Thanks. Would you, though, prefer several postal items over several pieces of mail?

I would argue that several mailpieces is AE whereas several postal items is more used in the UK.

mailspieces sounds like administrative language for postal workers...

No one normal would ever say that.

I was going to suggest items of mail.

@TinfoilHat (and KateB) I guess we don't normally think of a specific term for that and find our own ways to explain what we mean. I am just saying that there is a technical term for this.

"Postal items" is just wrong. Nobody would say that, ever.  If anything, "postal items" would mean "equipment used at a post office .. or something.

@KateBunting items of mail is fine but probably somewhat formal?  This is becoming one of those weird-ass questions on this site.  The OP said "But thinking of it, "pieces" seems a bit strange"  The answer is OP, good news, Piece of mail is 100.000% idiomatic and colloquial. This question is closed!  There's just nothing more to it.

?  The legal language definition of that legal term is utterly irrelevant, I'm afraid.

@Fattie - To my mind items is more idiomatic than pieces in this context; but of course the OP can say pieces if they want to.

I agree with @Kate (perhaps a UK/US difference?) – items is what I would naturally call them. Pieces of mail sounds strange to me, particularly if you remove of mail; for example, “I got three items in the mail today” sounds completely normal and natural to me, but “I got three pieces in the mail today” would leave me wondering ‘pieces of what?’.

@JanusBahsJacquet USPS: On average, the Postal Service processes 3,684 pieces of mail each second. https://facts.usps.com/one-day/ That's the term.

@Lambie Conversely, Royal Mail has a Send an Item service and, as far as I can tell from browsing their website, don’t refer to ‘pieces’ anywhere at all, so perhaps it is simply a UK/US difference that I just wasn’t aware of before.

As per Kate and Janus I agree that "Item" is definitely what would be used in the UK

@JanusBahsJacquet The reason you ask "pieces of what?" is because the usual phrase is "I got three pieces of mail today", not "three pieces in the mail".

@JanusBahsJacquet The Royal Mail is not the UK Post Office. They just say items for  letters and parcels.

@Lambie Royal Mail is not the UK post office (that would be Post Office, Ltd.), but it is the primary UK postal service, which is what handles sending and delivering mail. As such, it is the closest and most relevant equivalent to the USPS. And yes, they say ‘items’ for letters and parcels, which is exactly the term the question is asking about.

@JanusBahsJacquet The US Post Office is closest to the UK Post Office. Those are the comparables.

@Lambie No, it is not. USPS provides postal services; Post Office, Ltd. does not. But even if it were, it makes no difference. If you’d actually checked facts instead of harassing others about irrelevant technicalities, you would know that Post Office, Ltd. also exclusively mentions ‘parcels’ and ‘items’, but never ‘pieces’.

I'm a British English speaker, and would definitely prefer "items of mail" over "pieces of mail". "Pieces" suggests some concept of a larger whole, whereas "items" are discrete objects.
There are certainly some cases in which, despite the argument above applying equally well, "pieces" is entirely standard, and "items" would sound strange, such as furniture. But I don't think mail is one of them.
In fact, if I saw the phrase "pieces of mail" without any context at all, I would be expecting armour.

"Piece" can, but definitely does not need to, imply a larger whole. A "piece of cake" refers to a slice taken from the whole, but a "piece of fruit" would typically refer to something like a whole apple, which is not part of a larger entity. A piece of music, a piece of literature, or a piece of mail don't imply that they're part of anything, it means they are individual items.

"piece" is used when the whole is a collection, that's how it works for @NuclearHoagie's examples. In the case of mail, people often receive multiple items, so everything in the mailbox is the whole, and each item is a piece.

@NuclearHoagie I didn't say "imply", I said "suggest". By and large, but not absolutely, "piece" is used when there is some possibility of a larger whole. A piece of fruit certainly could be a whole fruit, but equally it could describe something smaller, such as a slice of melon. You can play several pieces of music consecutively and get some sort of larger whole (a concert or recital, for example). Talking about a piece of change literally comes from the historical practice of cutting up coins to make smaller values, etc. Even furniture could be, as in a "three-piece suite".

Regardless of your preference, "pieces of mail" it utterly idiomatic.  I'd likely understand you if you said "items of mail" to me, but it would be slightly jarring.  That's simply not what anyone I've ever been around actually says.

@JohnBollinger perhaps this is a BrE/AmE or other regional difference? Certainly ngrams suggests "items of mail" is very rare in AmE, whereas both are used in BrE. I shall edit to specify BrE.

@JohnBolinger, as others have said in comments to another answer, in the UK items is definitely more idiomatic than pieces. To us it "pieces or mail" that jars whereas "items of mail" sounds natural.

items of mail is formalistic sounding in the UK

coat(s) of mail for the win!

Yes, "pieces of mail" could describe a single parcel delivered in very poor condition.

@Fattie I think "pieces" is just as formal as "items", just with a different meaning. If I wanted to be less formal, I would say "bits".

If the exact number of items isn't important, mail is also a collective noun: Some mail.
While "pieces of mail" is certainly idiomatic (confirmed through Google Ngram) and I wouldn't fault anyone for using it, I share your feeling that it wouldn't be my first choice. I think it's because I think of mail as predominantly a collective noun (e.g., A bag of mail, Did the mail come?, Did you put out the mail?, etc.), and adding "pieces of" in front feels like I'm trying to force it into a count noun status.  Sort of the same way I feel awkward ordering "one large fries" at the drive through, no matter how acceptably idiomatic it may be.
If the exact number of mail items is important, another option would be to list each type of mail item individually; e.g., One letter, a couple of post cards, and one package were in the mail today.

in the uk we have a term called junk mail if that is what you are meaning, and  we would say

I have a bit of/some junk mail


junk mail noun
/ˈdʒʌŋk meɪl/
[uncountable] (disapproving)
​advertising material that is sent or
emailed to people who have not asked for it

oxford learners dictionary

Yes, though the OP seems to want to include junk, letters, cards, packages all.

@YosefBaskin Correct.

I only get bills and junkmail, so all mail -letters = junk mail

The term "junk mail" is definitely not limited to the U.K.

@user888379 I don't like to presume the whole world is the same as me.

Losing the junk-mail link, bits of post would also work.

"Items of mail" is more formal than "pieces of mail" and might be preferred in some contexts.

Just so.  It's not what you'd say normally.

It looks like "piece(s) of mail" has always been by far the most popular. "Article(s) of mail" used to occur in literature (more so even than "item(s) of mail"), but has fallen into relative disuse ngrams

I'm surprised the deverbal noun mailings hasn't been suggested yet. The concrete sense is perhaps not the default, but will usually be easily identified, where necessary, by context:

mailing [noun]

the action or process of sending something by mail.
an item sent by mail, especially a piece of mass advertising. [plural: mailings]


[ODE {ex Lexico}; courtesy of Google]                                [bolding mine]
Examples:


... mailings included only a reminder letter or a letter and another copy of a questionnaire.


[Sage Journals; courtesy of Google]


The members mailings included CBS and CBSN newsletters, reports, and leaflets from other associated organisations. [apostrophe doubtless required]


[arkivum; courtesy of Google]


The mailings included a proof copy of the book, as well as a bar of soap designed to look like a block of butter!


[The Publishing Post; International Women's Day: Marketing Highlights]

I would say I'd received 2 items in the mail.

What about missive? Though it's probably not suited for colloquial speech.
Merriam-Webster: a written communication : letter

The OP asked for a word that encompasses all kinds of matter delivered by post. "Missive" would not be used to refer to a parcel.
